# ActiveAdmin -- How to do processing on an uploaded image before the model's PaperClip takes over?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I want to do some processing on an uploaded image using RMagick before PaperClip which is specified in the model taken over.

**Is there any way to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the file data in the controller `params` before passing it into your object. You probably have something like this in your controller:

```
def create
  @model = MyModel.new(params[:model])
  if @model.save
  # ...
end
```

What you could do instead is:

```
def create
  file = params[:model][:file]
  # do something with it...
  @model = MyModel.new(params[:model])
  @model.file = file
  if @model.save
  # ...
end
```

I'm not sure how ActiveAdmin controllers work but you can probably inherit from them and modify only the actions you want to change.